# Keeping possible exceptions in Enum

Tags: java, enums

I am working on some workflow and it is possible to raise many exceptions in that. I heard that we can keep all those possible exceptions in an Enum (Exception1, Exception2 ...) and use it. How can we do that using Enums in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the classes of exceptions with

```
enum EnumWithExceptions {
    ENUM1(Exception1.class, Exception2.class),
    ENUM2(Exception3.class);

    private final Class<? extends Exception>[] exceptions;

    private EnumWithExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... exceptions) {
        this.exceptions = exceptions;
    }

    public boolean matches(Exception e) {
        for(Class<? extends Exception> e2: exceptions)
            if (e2.isInstance(e)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
} catch(Exception e){ 
    if (ENUM1.matches(e)){ 
        //do something 
    } else if(ENUM2.matches(e)) {
        //do something 
    } else {
         //do something 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error: the constructor parameter needs an elipsis as in `Class<? extends Exception> ... exceptions`

Comment: catch(Exception e){
 if e instanceof Exception1{
  //do something
 }else if e instanceof Exception2{
  //do something
 }else{
  //do something
 }
}How to change using enums if i have aboveblock?

Comment: @AshokSurya See my updated answer.  While you can do this, it is a very unusual requirement.  Is there a reason you cannot use standard try/catch blocks?

Comment: Thanks Peter. For sure, i am confused with enums. How can I catch Exception1 in code block. can i say,Catch(ENUM1.Exception1 e){}?

Comment: No, which is why I am wonder how enums will help you.  I have never seen someone trying to use enums with exceptions before.

Comment: shouldn't we use enum to have possible exceptions specific to a usecase?

Comment: You usually want to catch exception thrown by the try { } and these are most easily specified where the exceptions are thrown.  The handling of those exceptions is usually site specific as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I had just seen your website http://vanillajava.blogspot.in/ and found many interesting articles. If you don't mind, can i have your google talk id or skype id?

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Fred {
  SAM(AnException.class),
  I(AnotherException.class),
  AM(YetAnotherException.class)
  ;
   private Throwable t;
  Fred(Throwable throwable) {
       this.t = throwable;
  }
  public Throwable getThrowable() {
    return t;
  }
```

}

...

```
   throw Fred.SAM.getThrowable();
```

Comment: this would only save a single exception.

Comment: catch(Exception e){ if e instanceof Exception1{ //do something }else if e instanceof Exception2{ //do something }else{ //do something } }                                                                     How to change using enums if i have aboveblock?

Comment: I don't understand why you would do that and not have specific catch blocks.

Comment: For sure, i was confused with enums. How to catch SAM exception in code block.                                                           Catch(SAM e){}

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the exceptions in an ArrayList? Or if you want to name the index, you could use a HashMap.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public final class ExceptionStorage {
    private static int exceptionCount = 0;

    private static HashMap<String, Exception> indexedExceptions = new HashMap<>();
    private static ArrayList<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList();

    public static void addException(Exception e) {
        exceptions.add(e);
    }

    public static void putException(Exception e) {
        indexedExceptions.put("Exception" + (++exceptionCount), e);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Exception> getUnindexedExceptions() {
        return this.exceptions;
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Exception> getIndexedExceptions() {
        return this.indexedExceptions;
    }
}
```

Obviously you would have to modify the code to use either `ArrayList` or `HashMap`, but I think this would be a better solution than using Enums.